# Spring Boot not logs Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) on exception

Tags: spring-boot, logging, mdc

I need to have Mapped Diagnostic Context data in logs. Application build with:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

To get MDC in logs I put in **application.properties** file:

```
logging.pattern.level=%X{mdcData}%5p
```

and create a class

```
@Component
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            // Setup MDC data:
            String mdcData = String.format("[userId:%s | requestId:%s] ", "hello", "hello");
            MDC.put("mdcData", mdcData); //Variable 'mdcData' is referenced in Spring Boot's logging.pattern.level property
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
           // Tear down MDC data:
           // ( Important! Cleans up the ThreadLocal data again )
            MDC.clear();
        }
    }
...
}
```

The MDC data appears in logs when I use method call like `log.info("message here")`. I tried with levels **INFO, WARN, ERROR** - it is fine. But when I get **RuntimeException** in my controller, I see the stack trace in logs with **ERROR** level, but no MDC data provided.

What should I do to get MDC data in logs on exception thrown?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Were you able to find reason?

Comment: I just ran into this issue as well.  I think the problem is that Spring logs the exception outside the logging filter, after the finally block clears the MDC.  I'm not sure yet how to address that.

Comment: I confirmed that if I remove the MDC.clear() from the finally block, the data shows up on logged exceptions.  I think this is safe because Jetty uses a dedicated thread pool for handling requests, so the MDC will always be reset by the filter before any work is done.  Not 100% sure about this though.

Comment: @karlgold were you able to confirm if this is the right way to have the MDC data for the exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

You may write a block `catching` Exception before `MDC.clear()` in order to log in `doFilter` like below.

```
        try {
            // Setup MDC data:
            String mdcData = String.format("[userId:%s | requestId:%s] ", "hello", "hello");
            MDC.put("mdcData", mdcData); //Variable 'mdcData' is referenced in Spring Boot's logging.pattern.level property
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
        } finally {
           // Tear down MDC data:
           // ( Important! Cleans up the ThreadLocal data again )
            MDC.clear();
        }
```

It changes logger from DirectJDKLog to RequestFilter.

Comment: Might want to make sure to re-throw the Exception afterwards